# Upper bounds on the circut depth

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity

Suppose $f:\{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$ is a function such that it can be computed by a circuit of size $n^c$ for some constant $c>0$.

> Q. Is there any nontrivial upper bound on the depth of a circuit of size quasi-polynomial or subexponential computing $f$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Too long for a comment, hence, an "answer".]

It seems that, for *boolean* circuits, only logarithmic in the size improvements of the trivial depth are known: every circuit of size $S$ can be transformed to a circuit of depth $O(S/\log S)$ [Paterson and Valiant](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397576900906). For boolean (and arithmetic) *formulas*, the depth can be reduced to $O(\log S)$ (known as Spira's theorem). For arithmetic *circuits*, we can do much better than in the boolean case: then the resulting circuit has depth only about $(\log S)(\log d)$ and size $O(S^3)$, where $d$ is the degree of the computed polynomial: [Valiant, Skyum, Berkowitz and Rackoff](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0212043). Earlier, Hyafil (see the citation in the above paper) has obtained a similar upper bound on the depth, but the size increased until about $S^{\log d}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the references. Right now I accept this as an answer because it captures the state of the art of this matter.